# can scriptname be empty when supplying command-line arg?

Tags: python

using module sys one can get command line arguments like this

```
import sys
for x in sys.argv:
    print x
```

then at command shell[ubunto]

```
>>python file.py 1, 2, 3
```

this will print 
file[filename]
1
2
3
Now comes my doubt
in python documentaion 3.0.1 it is mentioned that

**If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.**

```
>>python  1, 2, 3
```

if i pass no script name , it will lead to error that 'can't open a file'. How would argv[0] be intitialized to an empty string when you are not passing script name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell, you can do something like `python -c "print 'Hello World!'"`, or you can put source code into python through a pipe. In such cases, no filename is available for python. In all other cases, Python will have a filename. Even if you use a shebang-line:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

and then call

```
./file.py 1, 2, 3
```

the shell will translate it to the correct interpreter call

```
python file.py 1, 2, 3
```